# make a frame with components visible only when needed in android

Tags: android, android-layout

Well what i wanted to do was create an initial layout which will have a toggle button and on clicking the toggle but it should make a frame visible which will have a few buttons or textviews.

Does anybody know how to do this in Android 2.2??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `visibility` attribute on a view to control whether it is visible or not.   Here's a small example that should do what you're looking for.

The main `Activity`:

```
public class DynamicLayoutTestActivity extends Activity {
    private ToggleButton toggleButton;
    private View possiblyHiddenView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        toggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
        possiblyHiddenView = (View) findViewById(R.id.possiblyHiddenView);

        toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(toggleButtonOnCheckedChangeListener);
    }

    private final CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener toggleButtonOnCheckedChangeListener
            = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                possiblyHiddenView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                possiblyHiddenView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

The layout file, `main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textOff="Show"
        android:textOn="Hide" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/possiblyHiddenView"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible"
    >
        <TextView
            android:text="Stuff that could be hidden."
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

If you don't want the hidden view to take up any space, use visibility `gone` instead of `invisible`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That defintly helps thanks you, but when it becomes visible it still messes around with the placement of the other views. What i really wanted was something which will be visible on top of the existing components and go away when not required

Comment: yeah kind of but it should have controls in it, i mean which can be clickable not just a ok or cancel button

Comment: Do you want ok/cancel buttons in addition to the controls?  Either way, you can extend Dialog.  
For example, there's a `DatePickerDialog`. That has controls and also ok/cancel buttons.

Comment: What i want to develop is something like this
I want a small pop up like screen which will not mess with my layout and can have textviews and a close button

Comment: It sounds like you want to create a custom subclass of `Dialog`.  I'll try to put together an example of this soon.

Answer (score 0):

If you're developing for Android 3.0+, look into [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html).